# MVC asp.net OutputCache Vary header missing from response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache, vary

When I use 
`Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)` and `Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["someValue"] = true;`
the `Vary` header is **missing** from the response!

There is **NO** problem with the `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)`  and `Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["someValue"] = true;` although. It Returns Vary: someValue

The same problem when using web.config and controller attributes

add name="myCacheProfile"   enabled="true" duration="3600"  varyByParam="*" varyByHeader="someValue" location="Downstream" Works and sends the Vary header

add name="myCacheProfile"   enabled="true" duration="3600"  varyByParam="*" varyByHeader="someValue" location="Client" doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use custom values, you must do an  override in the Global.asax.cs file:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(custom) && context != null && context.Request != null)
            {                
                HttpRequest req = context.Request;

                switch (custom.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "someValue":
                        return req.someValue;
                    case "USER-AGENT":
                        if (req.UserAgent != null && req.Browser != null)
                            return req.UserAgent.ToString() + "-" + req.Browser.IsMobileDevice.ToString() + "-" + req.Browser.Platform;
                        else
                            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
                    default:
                        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
                }
            }
            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
        }
```

Comment: No this is not VarybyCustom it is VaryByHeaders